# Android emulator closes when command prompt is closed

Tags: android, command-line, android-emulator

When I start emulator via command prompt with command below:

emulator -avd AVD_NAME

The emulator starts successfully.

But when I close the command prompt, the emulator also gets closed.

Can anybody tell how to prevent getting emulator closed, even if I close the command prompt ?

Answer (score 3):

Command prompt creates separate thread - you launch the emulator inside. When you close the cmd, you kill the thread and everything that is running in it.

Please refer to [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/9038/run-a-bat-file-in-a-scheduled-task-without-a-window) for guidelines on how to open an *.bat file without command window popping-out.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Any way I can start emulator in seperate thread ?

Comment: @Nuwisam this should not work. Calling "Start ..." will open new command prompt, in which "..." will be executed. So, you will be able to close the first command prompt, but second command prompt will be shown with the same problem described in question

Comment: Oh, I see. I am sorry for misleading you. I delete that suggestion from my answer. I will let you know when I find something more useful.

Comment: I used START /b emulator -avd AVD_NAME. But that poping-up another command line window. Cant we avoid the terminal window i.e. cant we just start emulator in single window ?

Comment: @sdkjain Does starting emulator from GUI satisfy you, or do you have to open emulator from command prompt?

Comment: @krossovochkin: I have created a .bat file as a short cut to start emulator via Command line commands, as an alternative to prevent going to eclipse and AVD.
Which is faster to open emulator.

Comment: As this is more OS related I would like to redirect you to people that knows the best about it - see my updated answer.

Comment: Just out of curiosity - have you found answer to your question? If you did, perhaps could you post it here for others that might have the same problem?